# Finding amplitude and phase response of an amplifier

Tags: amplifier, transfer-function, phase

I have a following problem, I have to find amplitude and phase response of an amplifier whose function is $$ H(s)={\frac {1}{s^2 + s + 100}} $$
I have solved simillar problems such as for this function $$ H(s)={\frac {1000s}{s + 10}}$$.
Where I got $$ Ф(jw)=arctg(∞) - arctg(\frac{w}{10}) $$ and $$ 20log|H(jw)| = 20log100 + 20logw - 10log(1 + (\frac{w}{10})^2) $$

Does anyone know how to get amplitude and phase response for the first function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First equate:$$ s = j\omega$$
then: $$s^{2} = -\omega^{2}$$
That gets rid of the squared term.

Then multiply top and bottom by the complex conjugate of the divisor and proceed as normal.

Comment: Yeah i did that before, but I don't get any 'nice' expressions. I thought someone might have other nicer solution .

Comment: It's a 2nd order system and sure, the answer is not as convenient as a first order.